# Calculate possible combinations with maximum and minimum length

Tags: combinatorics

For example, I got $5$ possible characters which can be used for the combination $a, b, c, d, e$. The minimum length of a combination is $2$ characters (e.g. $ab$, $ba$), the maximum length is $5$ (e.g. $abcde$, $abcdd$, $dabca$). I already figured out the following way of calculating possibilities.

$$(5^5) + (5^4) + (5^3) + (5^2)$$

But this formula is different for every different lengths. Also, it will get very long if the maximum length is higher. Is there a more simple formula for calculating it?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Here is a derivation of the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) for the $n$th partial sum of a geometric series.

Comment: Okay, I'll remember it for the next time^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about making a sum about that? For example, in your case, if you've got 5 possible characters and the maximum length is n, it would be
$$5^2+...+5^n=\sum_{k=2}^{n}5^k = \frac{5^2(5^{n-1}-1)}{5-1}$$

Comment: you can generalize this if the possible characters are $i$. Do that by yourself! I'm pretty sure you can do it.

Comment: I'm getting 3119 as result, while I got 3900 with the long formula I used before. Does it mean I were wrong with it or am I just to stupid to caculate it right?^^

Comment: i get both 3900 with your's and mine... 3125+625+125+25=3900
25(625-1)/4=3900

Comment: Okay, seems like I just failed it. After trying it again I also got 3900. One more question: Where/How is the minimum length "defined"?

Comment: i thought you defined as 2.. so the starting integer of the sum was 2, which is the minimum length

Comment: You're right. But I'd like to do "dynamically". Do you mean the 2 at 5^2? So I can just replace it.

Comment: I don't quite understand what's "dynamic", but the starting point of the sum should be $5^{minimum length}$ and the ending point of the sum should be $5^{maximum length}$